# Почему вместо reject срабатывает resolve?

Tags: javascript, promise

Этот код уходит в resolve:

```
Promise.resolve(Promise.reject(123).catch(v => console.log(v)))
  .then(() => console.log(1), () => console.error(2))
```

Но мне не понятно почему. Перед cath возвращается reject. Далее catch его перехватывает. Таким образом reject нейтрализован.

В итоге непонятно что именно заставляет срабатывать первый по счёту обработчик в then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

метод `.catch` возвращает поток выполнения в корректную ветку.

Чтобы продолжить выполнять ветку `reject` из `.catch` нужно так же вернуть `Promise.reject(...)`

```js
Promise.resolve(Promise.reject(123)
    .catch(v => Promise.reject(console.log(v))))
  .then(() => console.log(1), () => console.error(2))
```